# Disable Spring Security "Secure" setting on session cookie for DEV environments on localhost

Tags: spring-security, session-cookies

I am using Spring Security 6.2.0 and doing development on localhost the SESSION cookie is set using "Secure". This is causing Firefox to not accept the cookie because the service is using HTTP without LTS.

I need to disable this for localhost development.

I set the value of **server.servlet.session.cookie.secure = false** and have confirmed that the value is false when **AuthenticationSuccessHandler** is called, but the SESSION cooke still has "Secure"

Comment: without a working example this is impossible to answer.

Answer (score 0):

I am not using **application.properties**, the configurations are in AWS for each environment. Reading the value from AWS ignores the setting, but setting it on the command line works.

By adding the argument **-Dserver.servlet.session.cookie.secure=false** the "Secure" setting is removed from the session cookie and now Firefox works.

This suggests that the value is read at startup and never again after that, possibly set in a constructor.